# VB schema Import schema loading async

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, import, xmlschemaset

When loading a schema through:

```
Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
settings.Async = True
Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(inputUri, settings)
xmlSchema = xmlSchemaSet.Add(Nothing, reader)
```

The schema defined in the `inputUri` variable resolves using then proper `GetEntityAsync` function of the XmlUrlResolver. But the imported schemas resolve synchronously, which causes my ui to freeze while the schemas are being retrieved.

How do I make the automatic imports schema (provided during the XmlSchemaSet.Add method) retrieval asynchronous?
Thanks,
Kingman B